# How to narrow down an unknown variable to a general Record type?

Tags: typescript

What else do I need to put in the `if` condition so that TS accepts the type of the parameter for the function call? The current condition isn't specific enough and throws the error below.

```js
declare const unknownVar: unknown

declare function foo(record: Record<string | number, unknown>): void

if (unknownVar && typeof unknownVar === 'object')
  foo(unknownVar) // error
```

```
Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string | number, unknown>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could accomplish this would be to use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
declare const unknownVar: unknown

declare function foo(record: Record<string | number, unknown>): void

function isObject(input: unknown): input is Record<string | number, unknown> { 
  return typeof input === 'object'
}

if (isObject(unknownVar))
  foo(unknownVar) // no error!
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gVxQaxSQHcUA1WALh30JICg7RJYEAzXMDAS1XlaSQAKOMhjAqAJXBIxAHkwwuKAObwAPvBTYAtgCMQMADTUCxFAD4AlFQBuSLsAbsUnHinhc0AeV0ArcBiCSgAO2BhUuKYk1h4ooVie8FKiwPIYiirqmjr6Ria0FvAA3vB08PBwGNgw7hgAnsEgSKyx8fAAvJ3wAORIfgHddAC+DFwtQd79nIKRBeQwlpZlfAIzNGbzlvAA9NuaSPAGMDIAhEA)

Comment: This is at least missing a check that the variable is not null because `typeof null === 'object'` as well. Is the Record type really safe to assume with only the typeof check?

Comment: Yeah, you may need to fine-tune the predicate function a bit to suit your needs - mostly just wanted to illustrate how you'd use it in order to explicitly narrow the type of `unknownVar`.

Comment: My needs are that the unknown variable matches the Record type.